# How can I use "Supaz Easy Background" plugin adding a background video for WPBakery

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I've tried to use this https://wordpress.org/plugins/supaz-easy-background/ plugin for adding a video as background. But I'm not able to do this. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a class you want to use for your background. In my case it's "test".
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM6MB.png)

Then use this class in a row or section in WPBakery:
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOVrf.png)

Comment: Can you tell me how to use this plugin for Elementor please?

Comment: Same procedure for Elementor. Just use the class you assigned for your background in an Elementor block.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a custom `class` or `id` attribute value to any row element in WP Bakery using the row settings option. Check this [link](https://visualcomposer.com/help/content-elements-structure/element-id-extra-class-name/) for more details on how to add custom class or id in wpbakery.

Now set that class/id in the [plugin settings](https://ps.w.org/supaz-easy-background/assets/screenshot-2.png) as the selector for a parallax background image

Similar approach can be used for elementor or any other builder. Since all that plugin asks for is a unique CSS selector to set the background on.